# Android uiautomator - select multiple items at once

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to automate the contact selection process using Android [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html). My UI looks like below image. I am using below code to check each contact

```
for (String contactName : list) {
  UiScrollable scrollable = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(
      android.widget.ListView.class).scrollable(true))
      .setAsVerticalList();

  try {
    UiObject obj = scrollable.getChildByText(LIST_VIEW_ITEM, contactName, true);
    obj.click();

  } catch (Exception e) { }
  finally {
    scrollable.scrollToBeginning(scrollable.getMaxSearchSwipes());
  }             
}
```

This code is inefficient. It takes longtime to find each contact and check. Is there away to loop each row and check ?

Thank you.

[image: this].

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.CheckBox").instance(i)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure but I think it is supposed to work.

Try making a UiCollection (called checkboxes e.g.) of all the checkboxes and then checkboxes.click().

UiCollection inherits this method from UiObject so I would guess it clicks in each of them, but I haven't tried it. If it works I will edit my answer to remove the doubt :)